How to reduce file size of workbook that references links?
So I have a project where is receive 1500+ .csv sheets of data. Each file size is about 12kb and contains one column with timestamps, and one column with data that i need to extract based on the timestamp. Each sheet is sorted and grouped (these are power readings from rack PDUs in a data center, each sheet represents 1 PDU and each rack has 4 PDUs, they need to be grouped by rack). I breakup the 1500 sheets into chunks of around 100 for workability, and have 15 of these groups.
I process each individual sheet as a separate tab in one Group Workbook. I then have a Template file that simply references external link to the Group Workbook (i do this to sort/associate each PDU to the racks and this will be an ongoing thing for the immediate future). The file size for each Group set is around 6MB, but after it is processed and pulling data from external links, each of the Template files comes out to 100MB+, some are 200+ and can take a few minutes to open and save.
My process is clunky and inefficient, but it works. However, I will likely be processing more data in the future and expect larger files sizes and longer loading times. I'm sure there is a more feasible option that I am missing. It's becoming unworkable and I need some help to make it better. Thanks
enter image description here
Raw data that I receive (individual rPDU readings) ~12kb
enter image description here
I group them by location and process associated sheets as separate tabs in an index workbook. ~600kb
enter image description here
I then use a Template to sort/group is reading and reference links to the Index Workbook. This puts all the PDUs together sorted by rack. Then I total the readings, and get Peak, Avg, and Min. This comes out to 100MB+ file size

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

There are many reasons why the excel sheets are growing so large in size. This link might help: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/reduce-the-file-size-of-your-excel-spreadsheets-c4f69e3a-8eea-4e9d-8ded-0ac301192bf9. However, are you opposed to scripting this work load, because this really seems like it could be done with Python. Other languages could work, but Python is probably easiest. Especially since you are already doing so much manual labor, and expect it to increase in the future, taking the time to script this would probably be greatly beneficial to you in the long run.

Consider using Power Query to process data and load queries as connection only. Use pivot tables to summarize query data.

https://www.howtoexcel.org/reduce-excel-file-size/ Try the methods.
